# Dialog popping up but cancel and ok is not a function

Tags: javascript, aurelia

I am generally following the example from here:- https://github.com/aurelia/dialog#using-the-plugin

The modal pops up fine with my message however when I click `cancel` or `ok` I get

Uncaught Error: cancel is not a function
or
Uncaught Error: ok is not a function

It appears not to jump into the promise, also note sure if this is related but my controller.settings seems to be null as well.

in my **prompt.js**

```js
import {BindingEngine, inject} from 'aurelia-framework';
import {DialogService} from 'aurelia-dialog';

@inject(DialogService)

export class Prompt {

  constructor(controller){
    this.controller = controller;
    this.answer = null;

    //settings seems to be null as well?
    //controller.settings.lock = false;
    //controller.settings.centerHorizontalOnly = true;
  }
  
  activate(message) {
      this.message = message;
  }
}
```

in my **prompt.html**

```html
<template>
  <ai-dialog>
    <ai-dialog-body>
      <h2>${message}</h2>
    </ai-dialog-body>

    <ai-dialog-footer>
      <button click.trigger="controller.cancel()">Cancel</button>
      <button click.trigger="controller.ok()">Ok</button>
    </ai-dialog-footer>
  </ai-dialog>
</template>
```

In my main component

```js
...
import {DialogService} from 'aurelia-dialog';
import {Prompt} from './prompt';


@inject(..., DialogService)

export class Welcome {

    constructor(..., dialogService) {
        this.dialogService = dialogService;
    }


    reset() {
        this.dialogService.open({viewModel: Prompt, model: 'Are you sure you want to reset?' }).then(response => {
            console.log(response);
            if (!response.wasCancelled) {
                console.log('OK');
            } else {
                console.log('cancelled');
            }
            console.log(response.output);
        });
    }
    

  ...

};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two different classes (among other exports) that you can import from `'aurelia-dialog'`: `DialogService` and `DialogController`.

It seems that you are importing `DialogService` in your `prompt.js` class, but trying to use it as a `controller`.

Just replace these lines in `prompt.js`:

```
import {DialogService} from 'aurelia-dialog';

@inject(DialogService)
```

with these:

```
import {DialogController} from 'aurelia-dialog';

@inject(DialogController)
```

Comment: ah ta the wood and the trees! Thanks, will check it out later